# Php code taking too long time to run

Tags: mysql, excel, sql-insert

I am using **32bit windows machine on my local machine** and using wamp on local machine when i run one php code of taking data from excelsheet and putting it into mysql database its take **2 minutes** but when i run the code on my server it will take almost **22 minutes** to complete that task.

My server configuration
**64 bit windows machine** with wamp on it.

Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong.

Query:
**SHOW PROCESSLIST**

result

```
Id  User  Host               db     Command Time State Info
53  root  localhost:52760    test    Sleep   0         NULL
69  root  localhost:52819    test    Query   0   NULL  show processlist
```

Thank you
Gajanan Hiroji

Comment: Why do you think its related to 64bit?

Comment: Also what takes 22minutes? data insertion to the MySQL? or the taking of the data from the Excel?

Comment: Taking data from excel and inserting data into MYSQL is done by one single process..

Comment: Both machine are different so i thought like that..

Comment: What is taking 22minutes? you didn't answer, is it the opening of the Excel file or putting the data in. Try to find out, my guess is that Excel startup is long

Comment: Dear nrathaus. I have written read from excel and insert into MYSQL in one file. Which is taking 22 min. In another i am reading data from access database and inserting in to MYSQL database. This process also taking too long time to complete. So i feel inserting into database is taking time.

Comment: While the process is taking place, run on the MySQL **show processlist** it will list what processing are working, please provide the output here

Comment: Here you go `Id
User
Host
db
Command
Time
State
Info
Kill Kill
53
root
localhost:52760
test
Sleep
0
NULL
Kill Kill
69
root
localhost:52819
test
Query
0
NULL
show processlist`

Comment: Hrm, can you paste in your question, rather than in the comment, looking at it it lacks the "INSERT" i.e. there is nothing here to indicate that the INSERT is "long processing"

Comment: Can Anyone help me on this..

Comment: Your problem isn't the INSERT itself, as you can see during the time you were waiting there are no INSERT events. So the problem is elsewhere, I suggest to break down your code into portion, and add printing (to stdout/stderr) of where it is for each portion, so that you can see what takes a long time to do

Comment: Ok fine nrathaus. I agree with you but i am running 10 process on the same server each at a time but every process is taking long time. but the same processes are taking less time in my local machine. i am not able to figure out where i am going wrong. best example i can give you is there are two process in that one process is reading data from excel and inserting into MYSQL and one more process is reading data from access database table and inserting data into MYSQL database. so both process are taking long time to complete so I am feeling inserting in to database is taking long time

Comment: This conversation is a waste of time, if you cannot modify your code to provide you output on what its doing during those "lost 22 minutes" then I and probably no one else can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the difference between two machine. My local machine is dual core processor and my server is single core processor so it is taking so much of time to run the process.

Thank you for your support.

Gajanan Hiroji.